# Enviar muitas requests com axios sem que o codigo espere a resposta das requests anteriores

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Bom dia.

Quero enviar muitas requests sem que o codigo espere a respota das requests anteriores utilizando axios.

Meu codigo atual:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#central',
    data: {
        estilo: 'resize:none;text-align:center;color:red;width:450px;height:200px;font-size:15px;',
        capkey: 'text-align:center;color:RED;font-size:17px;;width:20%;height:40%;',
        ativar: true,
        buttonvalue: 'Inserir lista',
        livestyle: 'color:#519872;font-size:17px;',
        diestyle: 'color:#fd2eb3;font-size:17px',
        lives: [],
        dies: [],
    },
    methods: {

        async testar(rsrsrs) {
            await axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
                crossDomain: true,
                params: {
                    lista: rsrsrs
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    var resp = response.data.msg;
                    console.log(resp)

                    if (resp.includes("Live")) {
                        this.lives.push(resp)
                    } else if (resp.includes("reCaptcha")) {
                        this.testar(rsrsrs)
                    } else {
                        this.dies.push(resp)
                    }


                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },

        checkin(e) {
            this.buttonvalue = 'Testar'
            this.ativar = false
            var lista = e.split('\n');

            lista.map((value, key) => {

                this.testar(value);

            });


        }
    }
})
```

O problema é que o browser/codigo esta esperando as respostas das primeiras requests e assim demorando muito para processar uma certa quantidade de requests!

Como posso enviar e retornar requests de forma paralela ou sincrona ?

Comment: Olá Wagner, uma dica: ou o título não condiz com a dúvida, ou está errado. Pois o título fala sobre request no axios, mas internamente você colocou o VueJs na jogada, tente colocar um exemplo do problema sem o Vue se a dúvida é realmente sobre o axios.

Comment: Retire o *await* da linha `await axios`

Answer (score 2):

Em *JavaScript*, ao usar funções assíncronas com `async/await`, a execução da função para e espera (`await`) a resolução da `Promise`, no caso a chamada da *API*. Ou seja, o código fica parado, esperando a resposta do seu *backend*.

Você está resolvendo a `Promise` por meio do método `then()`, então não vejo motivo de utilizar o comando `await` e o `async`.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas